# Enum with decimal values or some like this

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, enums

Basically I want to define an enum with decimal values but this is not possible. An alternative is:

```
public static class EstadoRestriccion
{
    public const decimal Valur1 = 0;
    public const decimal Value2 = 0.5M;
    public const decimal Value3 = 1;
};
```

But I need add these constants in a combobox where the options to display should be the name of constants and `SelectedItem` should return the value (0, 0.5M, 1) or some like these. I know that it is possible but it is ugly.

With an enum I can do this easly: `comboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));`

What is the best way to simulate an enum with my requirements?

Answer (score 6):

A dictionary may be a good choice.

`Dictionary<string,decimal>` could be a good candidate - letting you name the values.

```
var values = new Dictionary<string,decimal>();
values.Add("Value1", 0m);
values.Add("Value2", 0.5m);
values.Add("Value3", 1m);
```

This can be wrapped in a class so you only expose a getter by index, instead of the whole `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` interface.

Comment: You could also have your dictionary `static readonly` and initialize it statically with an initializer list. That would behave a bit more like an enum IMO.

Comment: @Joce - You could still call `Add` on such a dictionary. You just wouldn't be able to _replace_ the dictionary.

Comment: Hum. True. :-/ Is there a way to declare a dictionary (or any type of complex object for that matter) to be a compile time constant?

Comment: @Joce - Not really. That's why you wrap such objects in classes that hide the extra functionality.

Comment: Maybe an inefficient solutions would be return a copy of dictionary so you can add values to it but the original dictionary is not modified.

Comment: @Overflow012 - It depends on the size of the dictionary. I don't see the point, if you already hold the data in memory and have a wrapper class to protect it.

Comment: @Oded Although I may have a wrapper there are some situations where you need add objects to a collection with some controls or something like that  (You can do `Foo.AddBar()`) and also you need return the collection (`Foo.Bars` or `Foo.GetBars()`) but you don't want to add objects directly (`Foo.Bars.Add()`) How can a wrapper solve this situation?

Comment: @Overflow012 - You have an `AddItem` method in the wrapper, delegating to the wrapped dictionary. The benefit being that you can validate there and then.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that you need sometimes return the collection too How can I do to not allow adding elements or modify the original collection?

Comment: @Overflow012 - You return a copy. Or write a wrapper that can do the work you need (implementing an iterator).

Comment: @Oded That is why I referred to return a copy in my first comment.

Answer (score 3):

THERE IS NO WAY simply. `enum` accepts only integer values. The code snippet you put is good.

There is a small difference between `const decimal` and `static readonly decimal`. The first is direct evaluation; the compiler replaces the name with its value. In contrast, `readonly` inforces the code to refer to the field each time and bring the value from it. You can observe why `readonly` is being used with reference types while `const` cannot be (expect for a string).

Comment: Yes. The OP did mention in the question it is not possible, but would like alternatives.

Comment: I don't understand. Why enum support hexadecimals but it doesn't support decimal, float, double???

Comment: @Overflow012 Because `hexadecimal` is really an integer. an `enum` only supports integer constants, which are used in a common manner (1, 2, 4, 16, 32,...) i.e. powers of 2. This enables the programmers to combine many options (e.g. `FileMode.Open | FileMode.Append`). However, `decimal`, `float`, and `double` types are NOT integers in C#, hence they are not supported

Answer (score 3):

You could change your class slightly:

```
public class EstadoRestriccion
{
    public static readonly EstadoRestriccion Value1 = new EstadoRestriccion("Value1", 0);
    public static readonly EstadoRestriccion Value2 = new EstadoRestriccion("Value2", 0.5M);
    public static readonly EstadoRestriccion Value3 = new EstadoRestriccion("Value3", 1);
    private static readonly EstadoRestriccion[] values = new EstadoRestriccion[] { Value1, Value2, Value3 };

    private string name;
    private decimal value;

    private EstadoRestriccion(string name, decimal value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static EstadoRestriccion[] GetValues()
    {
        return values;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
};
```

And some `decimal` conversion and/or change `value` to be a public property.

Answer (score 2):

How about a `static readonly` array of decimal?

```
public static readonly decimal[] myValues = new[] {0, 0.5M, 1};
```

Comment: But I could not display the name of value.